# Coding Implode In Twig

Tags: twig, implode

How can one use the equivalent of the [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function in a Twig environment?

For example, the contents of the variable `$data1 = "input your name"` and the variable `$data2 = "input your address"`.

How to create a variable `$result = "input your name, input your address"` in Twig?

Comment: I'm not sure I really get your question. I'm assuming you're talking about the Twig Template Engine for PHP, and want to assign the concatenated strings to a new variable? In that case it would be something like `{% set result = data1 ~ ", " ~ data2 %}`. But then I don't really get why you posted your question with '$'s in front of the variable names... If just want to output the two string, you could always do something like `{{data1}}, {{data2}}`

Answer (score 39):

I'm guessing you're looking for the [join](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html) filter. It works exactly like `implode` does in php. Quoting from the manual page:

The join filter returns a string which is the concatenation of the items of a sequence:

```
{{ [1, 2, 3]|join }}
{# returns 123 #}
```

The separator between elements is an empty string per default, but you can define it with the optional first parameter:

```
{{ [1, 2, 3]|join('|') }}
{# returns 1|2|3 #}
```